# How to transform UI control?

Tags: c#, wpf, transform

I am new to WPF.

I have following xaml -

```
<c:MyControl Fill="Red" Height="300" Width="150">
    <c:MyControl.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5"></ScaleTransform>
    </c:MyControl.RenderTransform>
</c:MyControl>
```

This code is working fine, but after transformation it is taking whole 300*150 space. I want it to take 150*75 space as I transformed it 50%. How can I do this? Which Transform shoould I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`LayoutTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.layouttransform.aspx) instead of `RenderTransform`.

```
<c:MyControl Fill="Red" Height="300" Width="150">
    <c:MyControl.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5"/>
    </c:MyControl.LayoutTransform>
</c:MyControl>
```